# Improving convergence in a numerical integration (Version 5.2)

Tags: numerical-integration, version-5

I have a double integral that I am trying to calculate numerically, and I'm having convergence issues.

```
f[x_, z_] := (Exp[-1*gamma*x]/x^0.5)*BesselI[1, (alpha*z*x)^0.5];
a[tau_, z_] := (alpha*z)^0.5*NIntegrate[f[tau - taup, z]*Exp[-1*gammaL*(tau - taup)]*Exp[-1*gammaS*(tau - taup)], {taup, 0, tau}, WorkingPrecision -> 200];
b[tau_, z_] := 0.25*alpha*z* NIntegrate[{f[tau - taup, z]*f[tau - taupp, z]*Exp[-1*(gammaL + gammaS)*Abs[taup - taupp]]}, {taup, 0, tau}, {taupp, 0, tau}, WorkingPrecision -> 200];
S[tau_, z_] := (1 + a[tau, z] + b[tau, z]);

gamma = 1;
gammaL = 10;
gammaS = 10;
alpha = 1;
```

Evaluating e.g. `S[100,10]` I get a convergence warning. From my understanding of how I'm expecting the integrals to behave, I think the answer I'm getting is incorrect. I get an answer of `3.259`.

```
NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 7 recursive bisections in taup near taup = 99.96171345046263`.
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration being 0, oscillatory integrand, or insufficient WorkingPrecision. If your integrand is oscillatory try using the option Method->Oscillatory in NIntegrate.
```

I've played with `WorkingPrecision` and `AccuracyGoal`. Are these the right things to try?

I am using rather dated Mathematica 5.2...

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I suspect it will help if you break that double integral into nested integrals, and break the inner integral into to parts split at the value of the outer integral -- ( thus getting rid of the `Abs` ).

Comment: Your function `f` has explicit machine numbers so you will not be able to evaluate it at any higher precision e.g. in `NIntegrate`.

Answer (score 2):

Your precison is limited by using machine precision numbers in your definitions (e.g., 0.5 (for Sqrt) and 0.25). WorkingPrecision cannot undo that. After correcting those, you can use a much lower WorkingPrecision (I used WP -> 20 below). Also, as a general rule, restrict the arguments of functions that directly or indirectly use numerical techniques (e.g., NIntegrate) to numeric arguments. You also had some extraneous list brackets within the NIntegrate used in the definition of b.

```
gamma = 1;
gammaL = 10;
gammaS = 10;
alpha = 1;

f[x_, z_] = (Exp[-1*gamma*x]/Sqrt[x])*BesselI[1, Sqrt[alpha*z*x]];
a[tau_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
  Sqrt[alpha*z]*
   NIntegrate[
    f[tau - taup, z]*Exp[-1*gammaL*(tau - taup)]*
     Exp[-1*gammaS*(tau - taup)], {taup, 0, tau}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];
b[tau_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
  1/4*alpha*z*
   NIntegrate[
    f[tau - taup, z]*f[tau - taupp, z]*
     Exp[-1*(gammaL + gammaS)*Abs[taup - taupp]], {taup, 0, tau}, {taupp, 0, 
     tau}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];
S[tau_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] :=
  (1 + a[tau, z] + b[tau, z]);
```

Even with WP -> 20 this is very slow

```
S[100, 10]
```

> 2.2970368792832342365

I cannot say whether this result is correct; however, there are no convergence or other warnings.

[Edit: This works with result as above in versions 10.0, 9.0.1, and 8.0.4 (also 7.0.1 but with slow convergence warning) but still gives errors and an incorrect answer in at least Version 5.2...]

Comment: Hi Bob, Many thanks - I should have spotted that.

Comment: Hi Bob, However, running your code and calculating S[100,10], I do still get convergence errors, and I get an answer of 3.259. I get this value independent of WP. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

here is how I broke up the integral per my comment:

```
 b = With[{tau = 100, z = 10, gamma = 1, gammaL = 10, gammaS = 10, alpha = 1},
       f[x_, z_] := (Exp[-1 gamma x]/x^(1/2))*BesselI[1, (alpha z x)^(1/2)];
       inner[taupp_?NumericQ] :=
         NIntegrate[f[tau - taup, z] 
              Exp[-(gammaL + gammaS) (taupp - taup)], {taup, 0, taupp}, 
                         WorkingPrecision -> 200] +
         NIntegrate[f[tau - taup, z]  
             Exp[-(gammaL + gammaS) (taup - taupp)], {taup, taupp, tau}, 
                         WorkingPrecision -> 200];
      (alpha z/4) NIntegrate[
                     f[tau - taupp, z] inner[taupp], {taupp, 0, tau}, 
                         WorkingPrecision -> 200] ]
```

result: `b=2.0883795336543203805702809..` and `1+a+b=3.34122664611074481970790113920060150969..........`

(after some hours) with a `failed to converge to requested precision` warning.  I get basically the same result (fast, without warning) without any `WorkingPrecision` specified however.